# Defining that nested relationships should proactively load in ORM classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, orm

I have three classes

```py
class A(my_declarative_base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = Column(sqlalchemy.types.Integer)

class B(my_declarative_base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    id = Column(sqlalchemy.types.Integer)
    fk_parent_a = Column(sqlalchemy.types.Integer, foreign_key(A.id))
    a = relationship(A, lazy='joined')

class C(my_declarative_base):
    __tablename__ = 'c'
    id = Column(sqlalchemy.types.Integer)
    fk_parent_b = Column(sqlalchemy.types.Integer, foreign_key(B.id))
    b = relationship(B, lazy='joined')
```

My goal is to be able to run a query such as

```py
session = Session(engine)
c_inst = session.query(C).filter_by(id=1).first()
session.expunge_all()
session.close()

# and then later

print(c_inst, c_inst.b, c_inst.b.a)
```

At present, trying to do this produces a `DetachedInstanceError` which I believe means that `c_inst.b.a` isn't being fetched when `c_inst.b` is fetched.

The options that I know would work are

1. do the printing before the session is closed
2. `session.query(C).options(joinedload(C.b).joinedload(B.a))`
3. use a `session.merge()` to attach `c_inst` to a new session

but it seems like it should be possible to force `A` to load (`lazy='joined'`) via the original ORM code in the same way that `B` is forced to.  How would I go about specifying that the nested relationship should also load?

Comment: The example code works for me without error.

Comment: Hm, I tried it a few more times producing the same error but after that, it reliably works now.  Weird